# Why $\{x: \limsup_nf_n(x)>a\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k \geq n}^{\infty}\{x:f_n(x)>a\}$ is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-sets

Why $$\{x: \limsup_nf_n(x)>a\}=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k \geq n}^{\infty}\{x:f_n(x)>a\}$$  $$\{x: \liminf_nf_n(x)>a\}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k \geq n}^{\infty}\{x:f_n(x)>a\}$$
are measurable?

If I know $\{x:f_n(x)>a\}$ is measurable, then the infinite union is measurable. But why $\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is still measurable?

Comment: Because intersection of a countable family of measurable sets is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intersection of any sequence of measurable sets is measurable since $\bigcap_n E_n=(\bigcup_n E_n^{c})^{c}$. (Complements of measurable sets and countable unions of measurable sets are measurable).